# jqGrid drag drop row re-ordering with server side data

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, drag-and-drop

When I drag and drop in `jqGrid`, I need to trigger a change in order for my items on the server side. I felt this would be a simple exercise, but I have yet to encounter a code example of how this can be achieved. I have looked at trying to use the jQueryUI events information, but the target is listed as the entire grid. I have been able to extract the source row Id from the `onstop` event via `ui.helper.context.id`, but I have had no luck what-so-ever identifying the dropped-on-item (and more importantly its id) within the list.

Just to clarify, I am dragging and dropping within the same `jqGrid` in an attempt to re-order the items on the server.

I have a jqGrid:

```
$("#modelList").jqGrid({
  url: getMSModelsJsonUrl + '?manuf=1',
  datatype: "json",
  colNames: ['ID', 'Name'],
  colModel: [
    { name: 'optionValue', key: true, index: 'optionValue', width: 55, editable: false, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } },
    { name: 'optionDisplay', index: 'optionDisplay', width: 155, editable: false }
  ],
  onSelectRow: function (id) {
    var manuf = $("#manufList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

    self.modelsTableInfo.currentSelection(manuf);

    $('#bodyList').setGridParam({ url: getMSBodiesJsonUrl + '?manuf=' + manuf + '&model=' + id }).trigger('reloadGrid');
  },
  loadComplete: function () {
    var grid = $("#modelList"),
    ids = grid.jqGrid("getDataIDs");
    if (ids && ids.length > 0)
      grid.jqGrid("setSelection", ids[0]);
  },
  sortname: 'optionValue',
  viewrecords: true,
  sortorder: "desc",
  caption: "Models",
  height: 350,
  rowNum: 1000,
  autowidth: true
});
```

and a drag and drop binding thus:

```
$("#modelList").jqGrid('gridDnD', {
  connectWith: '#modelList',

  onstop: function (event, ui) {
    var draggedItem = ui.helper.context.id;
    var dragTarget = event.target.id;
    alert(draggedItem +" to "+dragTarget );
  },

  beforedrop: function (event, ui, data, source, target) {
    return data;
  }
});
```

When something is dragged and dropped with the above code, it reports the source and target id as being the same.

I must be missing something here, as this all seems like an obvious use of the drag and drop functionality.

-- Edit ---

I ended up going for this solution that uses tableDnD as well, as I couldn't get jqGrid working (I'd love to see a solution though)

jQuery("#modelList").tableDnD({
      scrollAmount: 0,
      onDrop: function(table, row) {
        var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
        var rowIdBeforeNewPosition =null;
        for (var i=0; i

```
      if (rows[i].id === row.id) {
        if (i > 0)
          rowIdBeforeNewPosition = rows[i-1].id;
      }
    }

    var manufId = $("#manufList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

    $.ajax({ url: setModelOrderJSONUrl + '?manufId=' + manufId + '&modelIdToMove=' + row.id + '&modelIdToPositionAfter=' + rowIdBeforeNewPosition, type: "POST" }).done(function (wasSuccessful) {
      if (!wasSuccessful)
        $('#modelList').trigger('reloadGrid');  //Reload to reflect true situation
    });       
  }
});
```

$("#modelList").jqGrid({
      url: getMSModelsJsonUrl + '?manuf=1',
      datatype: "json",
      colNames: ['ID', 'Name'],
      colModel: [
        { name: 'optionValue', key: true, index: 'optionValue', width: 55, editable: false, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } },
        { name: 'optionDisplay', index: 'optionDisplay', width: 155, editable: false }
      ],
      onSelectRow: function (id) {
        var manuf = $("#manufList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

```
    self.modelsTableInfo.currentSelection(manuf);

    $('#bodyList').setGridParam({ url: getMSBodiesJsonUrl + '?manuf=' + manuf + '&model=' + id }).trigger('reloadGrid');
  },
  loadComplete: function () {
    var grid = $("#modelList"),
    ids = grid.jqGrid("getDataIDs");
    if (ids && ids.length > 0)
      grid.jqGrid("setSelection", ids[0]);
  },
  gridComplete: function () {
    $("#_empty", "#modelList").addClass("nodrag nodrop");
    jQuery("#modelList").tableDnDUpdate();
  },
  sortname: 'optionValue',
  viewrecords: true,
  sortorder: "desc",
  caption: "Models",
  height: 350,
  rowNum: 1000,
  autowidth: true
});
```

Comment: Okay, I gave up trying to get jqGrid to do this and switched to a solution using tableDnD - see edit